# Creating a multiple phone vCard using vObject

Tags: python, vcf-vcard, vobject

im using vObject to create a vCard. Everything works well except I can't add multiple phone numbers.

Right now i'm doing this:

```
v.add('tel')
v.tel.type_param = 'WORK'
v.tel.value = employee.office_phone

v.add('tel')
v.tel.type_param = 'FAX'
v.tel.value = employee.fax
```

As it's working as a key value, the work phone is overwritten by the fax number.

Any idea on who to do it right?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe `v.tel` needs to accessed like a list or an array, like `v.tel[0].type_param = 'WORK'`.  Or maybe `v.add()` returns an object, which is what you should assign the type_param and value to, like `tel = v.add('tel'); tel.type_param = 'WORK'`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `add()` method returns a specific object which can be used to fill in more data:

```
import vobject

j = vobject.vCard()
o = j.add('fn')
o.value = "Meiner Einer"

o = j.add('n')
o.value = vobject.vcard.Name( family='Einer', given='Meiner' )

o = j.add('tel')
o.type_param = "cell"
o.value = '+321 987 654321'

o = j.add('tel')
o.type_param = "work"
o.value = '+01 88 77 66 55'

o = j.add('tel')
o.type_param = "home"
o.value = '+49 181 99 00 00 00'

print(j.serialize())
```

Output:

```
BEGIN:VCARD
VERSION:3.0
FN:Meiner Einer
N:Einer;Meiner;;;
TEL;TYPE=cell:+321 987 654321
TEL;TYPE=work:+01 88 77 66 55
TEL;TYPE=home:+49 181 99 00 00 00
END:VCARD
```

Comment: How would I edit a current contact name? Right now the add function simply adds another line N. I simply want to change the current N line.

Comment: `j.n` should get you the current N line

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and did this :

```py
card = vobject.vCard()
        
card.add('fn')
card.fn.value = fullname
        
card.add('email')
card.email.value = email
card.email.type_param = 'INTERNET'
        
card.add('tel')
card.tel.value = cellphone
card.tel.type_param = 'CELL,VOICE,PREF'
        
if workphone != '' :
    card.tel_list.append(vobject.base.ContentLine('tel', [['TYPE:','work:']], workphone))
        
if fax != '' :
    card.tel_list.append(vobject.base.ContentLine('tel', [['TYPE:','fax:']], fax))
        
vcard_data = card.serialize()
```